# understanding onesixtyone SNMP tool

Tags: c, snmp, asn.1, mib

**Short Version**:
What does this (hex?) code found in [onesixtyone](http://www.phreedom.org/solar/onesixtyone/index.html) mean?

```
char object[] = "\x30\x0e\x30\x0c\x06\x08\x2b\x06\x01\x02\x01\x01\x01\x0\x05\x00";
```

**Long Version**:
Onesixtyone is search tool to find snmp enabled devices. It is hard coded to return the sysDescr.0 value. As a side project, I'm trying to understand and/or modify it to return any snmp OID value. I come from a PHP background, but I have used PHP to write linux daemons. I have limited knowledge of hex

My question: I'm repeatedly hung up by the build_snmp_reg method. My understanding is that it specifies the TCP packet being sent, but I cannot understand where the sysDescr.0 is found.

Comment: I'm not going to decode it for you but you'll need some knowledge of ASN.1 and the DER rules. For example the 0x30 0x0e means a SEQUENCE of length 14. Next we see 0x30 0x0C which means a SEQUENCE of length 12, and then 0x06 0x08 which means an OID of length 8 and so on.

Comment: Thanks. That actually helps alot combined with what i've been reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at some pretty low-level SNMP data there. You shouldn't have to do that with all of the SNMP tools around that will deal with that for you.

This hex that you're looking at is the SNMP PDU BER bytes. It's hard to answer your question, but maybe a website that explains SNMP PDU BER might help.

[Net-SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) and [LibSMI](http://svn.ibr.cs.tu-bs.de/projects/libsmi/) are what you should probably be looking at as well. Look around for whatever language and OS you're programming in and find SNMP tools and libraries for your project.